# Using Clickonce with xml config files

Tags: xml, clickonce

I have a windows forms app that I want to use Clickonce with.

I want to have a custom xml files for the app.

But what if I want to change it later, i.e. either replace
it or update it.

How would you do that with clickonce??

Malcolm

Answer (score 0):

If you as the developer want to change the xml file then you can just publish a new version of your app, and if configured so, your users will get the update automatically.

If the user wants to change it it is a PITA unless you use something like the settings functionality and provide a GUI for it.